# jquery slideshow without thumbnails?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a plugin for a simple slideshow without thumbnails.
I am working on the php side of the project so I can't spend more time on creating a slideshow.. so I thought I might just use a simple plugin for the slideshow that I need.

most of the ones on google has thumbnails or very bloated.. all i need is a light weight and basic (responsive if possible) out of the box slideshow for quick implementation into my project.

PS. I'm not asking anyone to write me a code. if you know any plugins then please do share.

something close to the image bellow:

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [**BX Slider**](http://bxslider.com/)? It is just a content slider, and capable of sliding basic `LI` or `DIV` content.

**Installation:**

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Comment: how come i didn't come across that one!! cheers mate. Carousel - dynamic number of slides is exactly what i'm after

Comment: Thanks... :) Just thinking who gave me the down-vote for no reason.

Comment: I know that @user3806613! :) But someone down-voted. Will be good if I knew the reason. Just saying that there are a lot of cowards here... :P

Comment: I know mate. you've been a member long enough to know people on STO will downvote for no reason! its turning to their hobby to login, downvote a few times and then loge off... anyway, I appreciate your help mate.